# Are there non-CLI implementations (esp, JVM) of the Boo programming language?

Tags: jvm, boo

[Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) looks like an interesting language, but it appears to be implemented only for the Common Language Infrastructure (CLI), AKA .NET -- at least, I haven't found any other implementation, and I'd especially like one for the JVM, if it exists. So, I thought I'd double check on Stack Overflow -- ARE there any non-CLI implementations of Boo?

Comment: heh, i like the guy that posted "try using python" -- he deleted his to lose the downvotes :)

Comment: Aw, I thought it was a funny and perfectly valid quip!-) Of course I know that Python (and Ruby and others) have good implementations on both CLI and JVM, and just wanted to see if I could use Boo without losing this kind of portability... but it still made me smile!-)

Comment: Heh. Yeah Alex, you might like Python. Don't be afraid to try it. :-)

Comment: Heh lol. Thats the funniest thing I have read all day.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Yes there is**. Check out the [boojay project](https://github.com/bamboo/boojay), it emits java bytecode.

Comment: Super!!!  Thanks.  I see it's in a pretty early stage, but seems to be actively developed and an excellent portent for boo's future!

Comment: Yep. Boojay was started by the creator of Boo. It was started after a challenge was made to allow Boo to multi-target.

Comment: Indeed - He lectured earlier this year at the PythonBrasil conference, and stated he is activelly working on boojay.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so. Given that the tagline is "A wrist friendly language for the CLI" it seems unlikely to be high on the list of priorities.

Answer (score 2):

From the [BOO manifesto](http://boo.codehaus.org/BooManifesto.pdf) (pdf link):

> A wrist friendly syntax, expressiveness and extensibility. That's not all.
>   I want my code to play nice with modules written in **other languages**.
>   I want a rich programming environment with a **well thought out class library**.
>   I want to be able to run my programs in **multiple platforms**.
>   **I want the CLI.**

You can try [Grasshopper](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=130) which can give you access to Java from IL (I think), since BOO compiles to IL it might work.

Comment: Ah well, that's the impression I got, but I was hoping to be wrong (all the "I want" except the last one are applicable to JVMs as well, and JVM has other pluses too -- App Engine support, different sets of libraries and frameworks, etc etc). Ah well!